# Jquery AutoComplete with inherited object paramater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery-1.9.0 and jquery-ui-1.10.0

```
var opts = {
            source: availableTags
        };

    var optsA = Object.create(opts, 
    {
        select: {
            value: function (event, ui) {}
        }
    });

    var optsB = Object.create(opts, 
    {
        select: {
            value: function (event, ui) {}
        }
    });

    $("#tags1").autocomplete(
        optsB
    );

    $("#tags2").autocomplete(
        optsA
    );
```

I am trying to build up two seperate arguments lists for my autocompletes. The objects seem to be constructed correctly but the autocomplete doesnt seem to recognise my definition for the select in the inherited objects.

Comment: It looks pretty strange. If you add select method to: optsA.__proto__ it works but if you add it to the object it doesn't...

Comment: I am thinking the Bind option you posted might be a better approach for solving this issue instead of trying to use classic OO concepts.

Comment: Obviously I am only sharing a little of my code, this is actually a much bigger argument list therefore my own insistance that its modularized.

Comment: I've fixed my answer, now it should work :)

Comment: Now I fixed the incorrect spelling too. Now it will work for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing property in the `Object.create` invocation.

You should add `enumerable: true`

```
var opts = {
    source: availableTags
};

var optsA = Object.create(opts, 
{
    select: {
        value: function (event, ui) {},
        enumerable: true
    }
});

var optsB = Object.create(opts, 
{
    select: {
        value: function (event, ui) {},
        enumerable: true
    }
});

$("#tags1").autocomplete(
    optsB
);

$("#tags2").autocomplete(
    optsA
);
```

The problem is that the for in loop in jQuery's core `extend` method can't find the `select` property because it's not marked as `enumerable` so that's why it's not accessible from inside the `autocomplete`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/308/)**

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work. It seems right to me but its not working, any ideas? How can I trouble shoot the issue. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Give me few minutes to post you jsfiddle example.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.9.0 and jquery-ui-1.10.0 it doesnt seem to work for this combination, any ideas or recommendations?  jsfiddle.net/EBduF/309

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of [object Object] is not a function. It happens at line 6952 of jquery-ui-1.10.0.js

Comment: Give it a function `source: function() { return ['list']; }`. If it works it's quick and dirty but anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24525/discussion-between-jonathan-and-minko-gechev)